# Dojo indirectselection handle check

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

How can I handle on check event on dojo indirect selection:

```
var table = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
    store: catalogLayout,
    structure: layout,
    id: "poolGrid",
    styles: "text-align: center",
    plugins: {indirectSelection: true}
}, document.createElement("div"));
```

This is my enhanced grid rendered on html:

```
<div id="contentNode" style="height:90%;width:100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See usage section of [documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/IndirectSelection.html). In your case

```
dojo.connect(table.selection, 'onSelected'|'onDeselected', function(rowIndex){...})
// when Select All checkbox is changed
dojo.connect(table.rowSelectCell, 'toggleAllSelection', function(newValue){...})
```